# Ejecutar una multiplicación en javaScript sin utilizar el operador matematico

Tags: javascript

Hasta el momento solo poseo este código, sin embargo me envía errores, según el problema tengo que hacerlo como si fuera una multiplicación echa a mano.

Hasta el momento solo se me ocurrió este código, sin embargo me retorna números sumamente grandes para los que ingreso, este sería el código de javaScript que tengo, disculpen si algo está mal echo, estoy empezando a aprender

```js
        var aumento = 0;
        var resultado = 0;
        var contador = 0;
        var array = new Array();
        function devolverMultiplicacion(){
            numero1 = document.getElementById('numero1_ingresado').value
            numero2 = document.getElementById('numero2_ingresado').value
            arr1 = numero1.split("")
            arr2 = numero2.split("")
            if(arr1.length > 3 || arr2.length > 3){
                alert("No puede ingresar numeros con mas de 3 digitos");   
            }
            else{
                for(i=arr2.length; i>=0; i--){
                    resultado = 0
                    numero_multipliacion1 = arr1[i];
                    for(j= arr1.length; j>=0; j--){
                        if(aumento == 0){
                            numero_multipliacion2 = arr1[j]
                            resultado = numero_multipliacion1 + numero_multipliacion2;
                        }
                        else{
                            numero_multipliacion2 = arr1[j]
                            resultado = aumento + numero_multipliacion1 + numero_multipliacion2;
                        }
                        if(resultado > 9){
                            aumento = resultado-9 
                        }
                        else{
                            aumento = 0;     
                        }
                    }
                    array.push(resultado);
                    contador += 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una multiplicacion es la sumatoria de un mismo numero A un cierto numero de veces B.

Para hacerlo sin usar el operador `*` puedes o usar una funcion recursiva...

```js
function multiplica(c, d) {
  return c > 0 ? multiplica(c-1, d) + d : 0;
}

console.log(
  multiplica(2,3),
  multiplica(3,4),
  multiplica(4,5),
  multiplica(5,6),
  multiplica(2,-6)
);
```

Tambien puedes usar un `for`

```js
function multiplica(c, d) {
  var r = 0;
  for(var i=1; i <= c; i++)
     r = r + d;
  return r;
}

console.log(
  multiplica(2,-3),
  multiplica(3,4),
  multiplica(4,5),
  multiplica(5,6)
);
```

Tambien puedes usar un poco de matematica, sin nada de algoritmos, dividiendo un operando por la inversa del otro. Esta forma te soluciona los problemas con numeros negativos y tambien funciona con valores decimales.

```js
function mul(a, b) {
  return a/(1/b);
}

console.log(
  mul(-2,-2),
  mul(2,3),
  mul(-4,4),
  mul(6,1.2)
);
```

Seguramente hay otras formas.

Nota: en ambas versiones debes usar un nuemero positivo en el primer termino, pero puede facilmente agregarse una validacion que resuleva esto automaticamente,

Comment: Aquello de la división es una muy buena solución !, puedo preguntar de donde lo has sacado ?

Comment: @kip de clases de matemática.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes ciertos errores, lo entiendo porque estas empezando pero creo que algo de lógica también es incorrecta, un pseudocodigo de lo que te piden seria esto:

```
// Verificamos que los numeros no sean mayores a 3 digitos
SI num1 > 999 O num1 > 999 
    'No puede ingresar numeros con mas de 3 digitos'
resultado = 0
// La multiplicacion es la suma continua del mismo numeros
// Esta continuidad o cantidad de veces de suma la define otro numero
MIENTRAS num2 > 0
    resultado = resultado + num1
MOSTRAR resultado
```

Entonces podemos hacer algo simple con JS

```
function devolverMultiplicacion(num1, num2) {
    if (num1 > 999 || num2 > 999) {
        alert('No puede ingresar numeros con mas de 3 digitos');
        return;
    }
    var resultado = 0;
    while (num2--) {
        resultado += num1;
    }
    return resultado;
}

devolverMultiplicacion(2, 9); // 18
devolverMultiplicacion(2, 12); // 24
devolverMultiplicacion(8, 9); // 72
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
   function multiplicar(){
 var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value), num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value);
 if (num1 > 100 || num2 > 100){
  alert("No puede ingresar números con más de 3 dígitos");
        return;
    }
 var multiplicacion = 0;
 const primer_numero = num1; //No es necesaria, sólo para el alert
 if (num1 > 0)
 while(num1){
  multiplicacion += num2;
  num1--;
 }
 else
 while(num1){
  multiplicacion -= num2;
  num1++;
 } 
 alert(primer_numero+" * "+num2+" = "+multiplicacion);
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:;" onsubmit="multiplicar()">
 <input type="text" autofocus>x
 <input type="text">
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

#### Explicación

Sumar `num2` a la variable multiplicación `num1` veces.

Por ejemplo, si `num1 = 2` y `num2 = 3`, entonces:

- 1er ciclo   `multiplicacion = 0+3    num1 = 1`
- 2do ciclo   `multiplicacion = 3+3    num1 = 0`
- 3er ciclo ¡NO ejecuta! Porque `num1 = 0 = false`. Acaba el ciclo y nos queda:

`multiplicacion = 6  = 2 * 3 = num1 * num2`